# Seleccionar sólo las vistas del usuario de una base de datos Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-10g

Estoy obteniendo las vistas de una base de datos en Oracle 10g con la siguiente instrucción:

```
select view_name from all_views;
```

Lo malo de esta sentencia es que me devuelve todas las vistas, no sólo las vistas `vista1` y `vista2` que creé con el usuario que uso para ejecutar la sentencia sql, también devuelve las vistas de sistema como `ALL_TABLES, APEX_WS_APPLICAIONS, WWV_FLOW_YEARS,` etc.
¿Qué debo hacer para obtener sólo las vistas `vista1` y `vista2`?

Al conectarme a SQLPLUS con este usuario y ejecutar `select * from session_privs;` resulta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Env vez de usar `all_views`, simplemente usa `user_views`. Esto automáticamente limita el resultado al usuario conectado.

Answer (score 0):

Luego de probar bastante, hallé no hay forma de filtrar `vista1` y `vista2` si antes no conozco el esquema al que pretenecen y si el usuario con el que realizo la consulta puede ver todas las vistas existentes.

La tabla  `ALL_VIEWS` es una de las tablas de Oracle donde éste almacena la matadata de la base de datos y muestra todas las vistas a las que el usuario tiene acceso. Esta tabla tiene una columna llamada `owner` que en el caso de Oracle es también el esquema de la tabla (lo mismo sucede con la tabla `ALL_TABLE` que contiene los datos de todas las tablas).
En mi caso, lo que debo hacer es filtrar las vistas por el `owner` o esquema al cual pertenecen, o darle al usuario sólo privilegios para poder acceder a las vistas `vista1` y `vista2`.

Más información aquí:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2117.htm#REFRN20305

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2105.htm#REFRN20286

http://oracle.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/oracle-sql-l/difference-between-all_tables-and-all_all_tables-4560379

Answer (score -2):

Prueba con:

```
SELECT * FROM VISTA1, VISTA2
```

Y le añades condición si prodece

No domino mucho Oracle, pero tampoco sé si te he entendido bien.